# Difference in OS X file names due to extended attribute or resource fork?

Tags: terminal, file, extended-attributes

I've done a *diff* on two file names (via Terminal), whose textual content on visual inspection appear to be the same file. *diff* however reports the two as differing. The only difference I could identify through Finder is that `file2` has a tag set, which `file1` hasn't.

I then did an `ls -l@` on both files and noticed the following difference:

```
Computer:Documents Alex$ ls -l@ file1 
-rw-r--r--  1 Alex  staff  67918 29 Jan  2009 file1
Computer:Documents Alex$ ls -l@ file2 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Alex  staff  67918 29 Jan  2009 file2
    com.apple.FinderInfo          32
```

Any ideas where the difference might come from?
Does the extended attribute for `file2` identify the tag? Is that stored in the file's resource fork?

Comment: What type of files are `file1` and `file2` and what's the output of `diff file1 file2` if the files are not binary files.

Comment: First of all, `FinderInfo` is not a resource fork.  FinderInfo is Finder metadata, like the color you assigned to a file in the Finder.  Second, fairly sure that diff is not resource-fork aware.  Are those binary files?  What's the byte-wise comparison output of `cmp`?

Comment: @user3439894 The files are Word files. I did a comparison of text, styles and properties, but I now realise that there might be more in there than just that. — @vykor Thanks for the info. Good to learn something new. I actually removed the tag from `file2` and the files (both are binary files) are still different. I've also done a `fc /b file1 file2` under Windows just to be sure and there are differences. The output from `cmp -b file1 file2` is
`differ: byte 34977, line 75479 is 204 M-^D   0 ^@` What does the `cmp` comparison do that `diff` doesn't?

Comment: So it looks like the two files _are_ different, thought they look exactly the same.